# protractor 2.0 get element by changing attributes

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Consider this html:

```
<my-toolbox my-toolboxtitle="{{entity.name || 'New Entity'}}">
    <input ng-model="entity.name">    
</my-toolbox>
```

Before upgrading to protractor 2.0 I could work with the toolbox like:

```
element(by.css("[my-toolboxtitle='New Entity']")).then(function(toolBox) {

    //do stuff with toolBox

    toolBox.element(by.css("input")).sendKeys(....);

    //still do some stuff with toolBox even though the title changed

});
```

The toolBox in the promise wouldn't change even if the entity.name changed. Now after upgrading to protractor 2.0 my tests fail with "No element found using locator..." after changing the name in the toolbox. Is there a way to keep the reference to the toolBox element?

Comment: Note that you cannot use `then()` directly on `element()` anymore ([reference](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/34f0eebd7e73b10e9b990caa06b63b6fd22b2589)).

Comment: thanks, I know that. As I said "Before upgrading"...

Comment: I edited the question, hope its clearer now

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the following should work as is:

```
var toolbox = element(by.css("[my-toolboxtitle='New Entity']"));
toolBox.element(by.css("input")).sendKeys("test");
```

Comment: but after that second line, I now need to get the toolBox again if I want to operate on it... in protractor 1.x the toolBox reference was still valid.

Comment: @roemer what error do you get if you use `toolbox` variable after "sendKeys" call?

Comment: `Message: Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("[my-toolboxtitle='New Entity'])"` plus a small protractor stack trace